# How do I reference a row from one in my second query

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have two queries

```
Dim query1 as String = "Select * from openquery (devbook, 'SELECT start_date FROM bookings WHERE investor = ''00000'' ')"

Dim FlightQuery as String = "Select * from openquery (devbook, 'SELECT price FROM flight_prices WHERE dep_date = start_date ')"
```

Where it says `dep_date = start_date` I need to grab the `start_date` from the first query and put it into my 2nd query.

These aren't my full queries they are more complicated and confusing than these but I put these as examples.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think What you are looking is `IN/Subquery`

```
Select * from openquery where start_date in (select start_date from investor where....)
```